# Can I apply for a new visa in UK before my Tier 4 Student Visa expires?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

Two part question here:

1. Can I apply for an ancestry visa (eligible) before my current student visa expires? Or do I have to wait till my Tier 4 expires THEN apply?
2. And if so, can I apply from within the UK, or do I have to go back to my home country?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From the [UK government website](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa) on the ancestry visa (bolding mine):

> You can apply for a UK Ancestry visa if you:
>
> - are a Commonwealth citizen
> - **are applying from outside the UK**
> - are able to prove that one of your grandparents was born in the UK
> - are able and planning to work in the UK
> - meet the other eligibility requirements

.

> What you can and can’t do
>
> You can:
>
> - work
> - study
> - bring family members
>
> You can’t:
>
> - **change (‘switch’) into this visa if you’re already in the UK on
>     another visa**
> - get public funds

It doesn't appear that you have to wait until your current visa expires, but you **do** have to wait until you have returned to your home country